# How to test a sandbox class in jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am using ngrx and sanbox layer approach in a angular4 app.
Currently i am stuck in testing a sandox.Below is how i am writing spec for my sandbox class

Sandbox code:

```
 @Injectable()
 export class MonitoringSandbox {
 constructor(public deviceService: DeviceService,
    public appStateManagerService: AppStateManagerService) {
  }

 public getDeviceIdWithRowIndex(): Observable<Array<RowIdDeviceIdKeyValue>> {
    return 
    this.appStateManagerService.getFromStore<Array<RowIdDeviceIdKeyValue>>(
        state => state.devicesState.kvRows
    );
}

public setSelectedDevice(deviceId: string) {
    this.appStateManagerService.saveToStore(new SetSelectedDevice(deviceId));
}
```

Sandboxs spec.ts

```
 describe('Monitoring Sandbox', () => {
 beforeEach(
 async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [UnitTestsModule]
  });
 })
);
beforeEach(inject([MonitoringSandbox], (monSandbox: MonitoringSandbox) => {
  this.MonitoringSandbox = monSandbox;
})
);
/* teh failing test */
it('Should get and set selected row  value from session storage for selected 
 row', () => {
let selectedRow: string;
this.MonitoringSandbox.setSelectedRow('143');
selectedRow = this.MonitoringSandbox.getSelectedRow();
expect(selectedRow).toEqual('143');
});
```

I am getting below error :

Chrome 68.0.3419 (Windows 7 0.0.0) 
Monitoring Sandbox Should get and set selected row  value from session storage for selected row FAILED

Error: StaticInjectorError[MonitoringSandbox]:
        error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ Function ] })

Where am i going wrong in injecting the sandbox class, apprantely the sandbox object is coming undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of your testbed :

```
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [UnitTestsModule]
  });
```

There's no dependency related to your Sandbox.

Furthermore, I don't know what a Sandbox is in this context, maybe you could provide some code to help ùe understand and give you a solution suited for this issue ?

#### EDIT

Your sandbox is a service (it's decorated with `@Injectable`), so you need to import it into your testbed.

Since you don't test the sandbox, but your component, you will need to mock it.

This looks like this :

```js
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [UnitTestsModule],
    providers: [
      { provide: MonitoringSandbox, useValue: {
        getDeviceIdWithRowIndex: () => Observable.of(/* an array of RowIdDeviceIdKeyValue */),
        setSelectedDevice: () => null // does nothing, so no return needed
      }}
    ]
  });
```

#### EDIT 2

```
this.MonitoringSandbox = monSandbox;
```

This line means nothing. Replace it with this

```
sandboxMock: MonitoringSandbox; // place it as the first line of your describe
```

And in your before each, do that

```
beforeEach(() => {
  sandboxMock = TestBed.get(MonitoringSandbox);
})
```

Comment: i am unable to understand how to add dependency and I have added code of the sandbox

Comment: I am still getting same error if I run the test.I have updated the question to show the failing test